# Configure multiple project files in Stryker.Net test

Tags: .net, mutation-testing, stryker, stryker-net

I have a Stryker test with this `stryker-config.json`:

```json
{
  "stryker-config": {
    "reporters": [
      "progress",
      "html",
      "json"
    ],
    "log-level": "info",
    "log-file": true,
    "timeout-ms": 10000,
    "project-file": "Eb.MarketFeed.Domain.csproj",
    "max-concurrent-test-runners": 4,
    "threshold-high": 80,
    "threshold-low": 70,
    "threshold-break": 60
  }
}
```

My test `.csproj` file contains two project references though:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Eb.MarketFeed.Domain\Eb.MarketFeed.Domain.csproj" />
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Eb.MarketFeed.Decoders\Eb.MarketFeed.Decoders.csproj" />
```

Is there any way I can edit my `stryker-config.json` to include both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately there's no way currently.

You'll basically need to run mutation testing subsequently against both projects. Remember you can keep most of the config file, just pass the specific project to the Stryker command line using `-p`/`--project-file` option, so it will look like `dotnet stryker --config-file-path PATH --project-file PROJECT`.

Alternatively, if you have a solution, you can look into ideas in [this discussion](https://github.com/stryker-mutator/stryker-net/discussions/1234#discussioncomment-370087). Basically it's either unstable or you'll require some manual scripting.